# How to force browser to fetch new SSL certificate instead of old one using server side configuration (Nginx)?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, ssl-certificate

We have a website with SSL configured. 2 days back SSL certificate was expired so I purchased a new instead of renewing. I have configured the new one. Now some of users are still getting SSL certificate expired issue although the new one is configured.

I want to force the browser to recheck the new SSL certificate using some server side configuration since we can not go and update each user browser certificate manually. It have to be done using some server side configuration. We are using Nginx.

This is really critical to us.

Please help in this regard.

Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, on Edge browser, I am able to force loading of a new SSL once I delete "cached images and files."

Answer (score 3):

The certificate is validated by the client only when the server sends one. The server sends one with each full TLS handshake. The browser does not somehow cache an old certificate and ignore the one sent by the server when validating.

It is more likely that you've not fully rolled out the new certificate on the server side. For example if you have multiple servers make sure that all have the new certificate. If your server provides access for IPv4 and IPv6 make sure that in both cases the proper certificate is served. If you provide service on multiple ports make sure that they all use the new certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But we are using just two EC2 machine with first one having tomcat server and other with Wordpress site. I have updated new SSL certificate on both EC2. But still some users are facing this problem. Is there any cache that I need flush?

Comment: @pankaj: As I said there is no cache for this on the browser site. But I'm not familiar  enough with EC2 to know if anything need to be done at the server side. Maybe more details about which kind of clients are affected (specific geographical region, specific ISP, specific browser ...) would help to narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hey! Problem was solved by adding Root CA certificate. It was missing there. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible your affected users are behind a proxy that caches certificates. For example if they're behind a Smoothwall proxy that generates its own certificates after inspecting HTTPS traffic and caches them.

Either way, if you've updated the certificates on your server and restarted the necessary services, it's probably nothing you have control over and will most likely resolve itself in time.